# iCal sync with database

Tags: php, iphone, calendar, icalendar, caldav

Let's say I have a PHP file that generates an iCal calendar (file.ics) and I import this file in my smartphone.

My question is: how do I sync the changes made on the smartphone with the server that hosts the iCal file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncing is not that easy and plain process as just importing the data, and cannot be described here in 'easy steps'. There is an API on iPhone to access calendars data, via it you should check the data, understand which records were changed locally and on remote server, and decide what to copy, what to delete, where are conflicts, etc.

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply.

What you're saying is that I need an app to retrieve the changes on the iPhone calendar? There's nothing I can do with the native app?

Like Google Calendar: if I change something on the local calendar, it changes on the Google Calendar account too.

Comment: Google calendar uses CalDAV server, so all the data from iPhone is synced by iPhone applications via CalDAV protocol. You can do the same by setuping CalDAV server on your location.

Comment: Thank you again. Do you have any suggestion on what should I begin with to start a CalDAV server?

Comment: I guess, you should start by reading wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV :)